# Spring and Thymleaf

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

Is it possible to insert model data in the following manner

for example
In Spring Controller

```
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(viewName);
String id = SessionUtil.getUserId(request);
boolean isUserLoggedIn = SessionUtil.isValidSession(request);    
mv.addObject("isUserLoggedIn", isUserLoggedIn);
**mv.addObject("id", id );**
```

In the thymeleaf view template

```
   <ul class="nav nav-list" th:attr="ng-init='getNavigation(${id})'">
```

I was hoping to get ...ng-init='getNavigation(1)'>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thymeleaf doesn't do string templating in the manner you've shown, so you either need to concatenate the strings with variable expression:

```
th:attr="ng-init='getNavigation('+${id}+')'"
```

or enclose strings with variable expression:

```
th:attr="ng-init=${'getNavigation('+id+')'}"
```

(both bear the same amount of characters so it's purely a matter of taste; I guess, for me the first one looks a bit more readable though)

Comment: Thank You this worked with some modification on my code also.  For the line ....mv.addObject("id", id ); i had to switch to mv.addObject("id", "\""+id +"\"" ); Without this fix I was getting an undefined value once it was evaluated. I am also using AngularJS could this be conflicting with some of their syntax?

Comment: I'd advise to rather add the quotes in the view layer, like `th:attr="ng-init='getNavigation(\"'+${id}+'\")'"`. One could say you don't really need thymeleaf at all if you're using AngularJS because they AngularJS may do all the things that Thymeleaf can, so you may stick with pure HTML instead of Thymeleaf, but to answer your question – no, usage of Angular does not alter Thymeleaf's syntax, although it is certainly easy to get a bit confused with the amount of quotes one may need with this mix. BTW, please accept my answer if you consider it satisfying :).